# Jquery scroll fade between divs

Tags: jquery, scroll, fade

OK, so I have a few divs going down the page, mostly with common CSS of height: 1024px and width:100%. Each of these divs have a full screen background image set using backstretch.

What I want to do is have all the divs hidden at first with only the first one showing - then as you scroll down the page I want each div to fade in with the existing div fading out and visa versa as you scroll back up.

As you can see I have set the existing divs to all height of 1024 so I dont mind if you can see a blank area at the bottom of the screen on higher resolutions.

I have tried using the scrolltop() function but it doesnt work reliably.

Comment: can you add html or jquery what you have tried ?

Comment: if you see it firebug then you will notice they just adding toggling classes when scroll down and up..

Comment: so how would I do that?

Comment: http://www.ixistore.be/js/scroll.js take a look at this code

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var main = Math.min(0.5 + 0.4 * $(this).scrollTop() / 3000, 0.9);
        var change = Math.round(main * 255);
        $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + change + ',' + change + ',' + change+ ')');
    });
});

</script>
```

**For background**

```
var pW = $(this).scrollTop();
$(this).css('background-position', '0% ' + parseInt(-pW / 10) + 'px');
```

create sprite `css` image and set image accordingly.

Comment: OK, that is ideal, but how would i incorporate that using the jquery backstretch for full screen background image?

Comment: @Palemo see update answer you can change background position.

Comment: So, I replace everything from scroll(function() to }); (ie. var main, var change, $("body") etc

Comment: @Palemo you can i gave you example for changing background you can choose either one

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot get it to work - can you give me the full code for changing the background on scroll? I likely cannot use it as one image because the site is using backstretch

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
     {
        $('div1').fadeOut();
     }
    else
     {
        $('div2').fadeIn();
     }
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, am looking for something like http://www.ixistore.be/ -> that is as you scroll down the page it fades out the existing div and fades in the next div and visa versa.